# Hunting for a malware

Tags: linux, strace, malware, trace

I'm hunting a malware under my linux .mozilla folder. My first step is try to log all opened files during  running of firefox. What do you advice me to use for this purpose ? Strace ? Are there other tools ? not lsof because I don't know if the file will be closed after loading.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple tools available.

For a job like this `strace -f '-e%file' firefox` is fine. It is not the most efficient as each system call requires multiple context switches between kernel and user space.

Tools which do this more efficiently instead write information to buffers in the kernel which are then read out. `perf trace` may be already installed on your system. Lots of the tracing world is switching to using [ebpf](https://ebpf.io/). Whilst you can write low level code to use ebpf, there are high level tools to handle lots of the common cases. [tracee](https://github.com/aquasecurity/tracee) is a new tool. [bpftrace](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace) is a more established one.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Firefox extension, delete it.

If it's a real piece of malware, i.e. a binary, consider your system compromised beyond repair including all your passwords. Reinstall from scratch, reset all your passwords.

I would also reflash EFI firmware just to be sure.

Comment: I'm sorry your comment is very common and absolutely not useful. If I don't know where is the malware and how the infection was been injected then reinstall from scratch is a non sense. If the malware is injected by a jpeg image when I restore it from  backup my pc will be reinfected again. So BEFORE you must detect the malware and know where is it and AFTER you can reinstall.

Comment: @Lews You don't use a backup for a reinstall, it's a reinstall. The purpose of a reinstall is to assume your whole system is compromised, as you're not sure where the infection is coming from.

Comment: @cutrightjm LOL